# Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

Tags: solidity

I wrote one contract to call a function from another contract like below

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract test3 {       
    address watch_addr = address(0x1234567963); //deployed contract address

    function balanceOf(address owner) public {
        watch_addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("balanceOf(address)", owner));
        return balanceOf(owner);
    }
}
```

I want to call a `balanceOf` function in deployed contract.Now I deployed the new contract successfully but I am getting the following error while calling the `balanceOf` function

> error:"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below).
>   The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force
>   sending? "

Can any one please tell me the solution? --Thanks

Comment: `balanceOf` calls itself every time, so you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `balanceOf` inside `balanceOf` , so it will be executed infinitely. Real estimation of gas for such actions are not possible or infinite. That's why you are getting this error. With smart contract, be damn sure with your logic.